# Problems in opening MySQL Query Browser

Tags: mysql

My MySQL Query Browser doesn't run. I just started to work with XAMPP and PHP.

I just installed XAMPP on my local machine. Now I have a problem when opening MySQL Query Browser. What I'm getting while trying to open it is:

> Could not connect to host 'localhost'. MySQL Error Nr. 2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
>
> Click the `Ping` button to see if there is a networking problem.

Can anyone help me to fix the above problem?

Comment: Obvious question: do you have a MySQL server to browse queries against?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already being answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376427/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-mysql-mysql-sock-38:

> If your file my.cnf (usually in the */etc/mysql/* folder) is correctly configured with
>
> ```
> socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> ```
>
> you can check if mysql is running with the following command:
>
> ```
> mysqladmin -u root -p status
> ```
>
> try changing your permission to mysql folder. If you are working locally, you can try:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
> ```
>
> that solved it for me